# Reading Excel files where Office is not installed using PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell, office-interop

I am trying to read Excel file using PowerShell. My script works on my machine but it generates the following error when I run it on the server where MS Office is not installed. The client will not intall MS Office on the server. How can I solve this problem?

Error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Script:

```
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
```

I have tried to load `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll` in my script by coping it to the server. But it doesn't help.

I have tried this solution [this solution](http://powershell-tips.blogspot.se/2012/07/reading-updating-and-inserting-data.html), but it generates `microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0 provider is not registered on the local machine`

Comment: You should probably export your files in CSV format and then call `Import-CSV` from Powershell to read the data. And yes, "just" copying the DLL won't do, you need at least partial install of MS Office that includes MS Excel to make calls for `New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"` work.

Comment: You can't create an instance of `Excel.Application` without Excel being installed. (Excel is the `Excel.Application` you're trying to create an instance of, and clearly you can't do so if it doesn't exist.)

Comment: unzip the excel file, and use XML?

Comment: do yoy mean, first save it as zip and then unzip it and open sheet1.xml, because it is so big that VS cannot open it.

Answer (score 3):

Try [EPPlus libary](http://epplus.codeplex.com). It's a .net library that reads and writes Excel 2007/2010 files using the Open Office Xml format (xlsx).

There at least three PowerShell modules available, that use that library:

- [PSExcel](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSExcel). More info: [PSExcel: Excel automation without Excel](http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/PSExcel-Intro/)
- [ExcelPSLib](https://excelpslib.codeplex.com)
- [ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel)

Comment: thanks, I tried to use psxcel but it generates following error do you know why it cannot find officeopenxml? Cannot find type [OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded.

Comment: @user217648 Have you imported the module? Try this `Import-Module -Name 'X:\Path\To\PSExcel'`

Comment: Yes, I have imported PSExcel

Comment: @user217648 I've looked at the source code and it seems like it uses [ExcelPackage: Office Open XML Format file creation](https://excelpackage.codeplex.com/). Download binary, import it with `Add-Type -Path 'X:\Path\To\ExcelPackage.dll '` and see if it helps.

Comment: No it doesn't work, now it complains that I send error number of headers, but I send right header. the excel sheet has three columns and i send three header same name as columns.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I solved this problem using OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.